Extension of lifting
Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a measure space, and $\mathcal{L}^\infty_\mathcal{A}$ be the space of all bounded $\mathcal{A}$-measurable functions. Consider the following definition:

A map $L:\mathcal{L}^\infty_\mathcal{A}\rightarrow\mathcal{L}^\infty_\mathcal{A}$ is called a lifting on $\mathcal{L}^\infty_\mathcal{A}$ if:

$L(f)=f$ $\mu$-a.e.
If $f=g$ $\mu$-a.e. then $L(f)(x)=L(g)(x)$ for every $x\in X$
If $f=1$ $\mu$-a.e. then $L(f)(x)=1$ for every $x\in X$
$L(\alpha f+\beta g)(x)=\alpha L(f)(x)+\beta L(g)(x)$ for every $x\in X$
$L(fg)(x)=L(f)(x)L(g)(x)$ for every $x\in X$


Suppose now that we have a map $L$ defined only on the simple functions of $\mathcal{L}^\infty_\mathcal{A}$ that satisfies the above-listed properties. I want to extend it to all of $\mathcal{L}^\infty_\mathcal{A}$, knowing that every bounded $\mathcal{A}$-measurable function is the uniform limit of a sequence of simple functions, so I tried to define it as $L(f)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}L(f_n)$ where $\{f_n\}$ is such a sequence, but this doesn't seem to work (probably is also not well-defined). Bogachev (Measure Theory, chapter 10.5) says that we can define it by means of uniform approximation, which isn't clear to me what it means. Ionescu-Tulcea (Proposition 2 of this) says that since the set of simple functions is dense in $\mathcal{L}^\infty_\mathcal{A}$ with respect to the topology induced by the essential sup semi-norm, we can extend $L$ by continuity to all the space, and such extension is a lifting (it respects the listed properties): what does it means? I know that basically it means that $L(f):=\lim_{\phi\rightarrow f} L(\phi)$ where $\phi$ are the simple functions, but my question are:

With respect of what norm are we doing the limit? The sup norm or the essential sup (semi)-norm?
Why does this limit exists and why it is unique?
Why such an $L$ satisfies the above listed properties?

Edit: Also I don't understand why Ionescu-Tulcea talks about the simple functions being dense with respect to the ess-sup semi norm. Since every $f\in\mathcal{L}^\infty_\mathcal{A}$ is the uniform limit of a sequence $\{f_n\}$ of simple functions, doesn't this means that $\|f_n-f\|_\infty\rightarrow 0$, i.e. that the simple functions are dense with respect to the sup norm?

It is true that $\mathcal A$-simple functions are dense in $\mathcal L^\infty_{\mathcal A}$ for the topology defined by the seminorm $f\mapsto\operatorname{ess sup}|f|$ since it is coarser than the topology defined by the norm $f\mapsto\sup|f|$, but both limits ($\phi\to f$ and $\lim_{\phi\to f}L(\phi)$) should be understood with the norm $f\mapsto\sup|f|$. So for all that follows, consider that the topology on $\mathcal L^\infty_{\mathcal A}$ is the one defined by $f\mapsto\sup|f|$.
$\mathcal L^\infty_{\mathcal A}$ can be checked to be a Banach algebra and $L$ can be checked to be continuous, so since it is also linear, it is uniformly continuous and existence and uniqueness of the limit is a consequence of a classical result about the extension of uniformly continuous maps with values in a Hausdorff and complete uniform space.
Properties 3., 4., 5. for the extension of $L$ follow from $L$ being a unital algebra homomorphism (since $\mathcal L^\infty_{\mathcal A}$ is a unital topological algebra, the extension of $L$ must also be a unital algebra homomorphism).
Property 2. follows from $L$ and its extension being linear and from the fact that if $f$ and $g$ are $\mathcal A$-measurable, bounded and coincide almost everywhere, then $f-g$ can be approximated uniformly with $\mathcal A$-simple functions which are $0$ almost everywhere.
Property 1. follows from the function $f\mapsto\operatorname{ess sup}|L(f)-f|$ from $\mathcal L^\infty_{\mathcal A}$ to $\mathbf R$ being continuous and being $0$ on the dense subset of $\mathcal L^\infty_{\mathcal A}$ consisting of all $\mathcal A$-simple functions.

Thank you, just two questions: can you elaborate on why $f-g$, that is $0$ almost everywhere, is the uniform limit of a sequence of $0$ a.e. simple functions? And second question, why the extension of $L$ is still a unital algebra homomorphism?

@LuigiTraino If $n>0$, let
$$h_n(x)=\sum_{k\in\mathbf N}\frac kn(\mathbf 1_{[k/n,(k+1)/n)}-\mathbf 1_{[-(k+1)/n,-k/n)})((f-g)(x))$$
for every $x\in X$; since $f-g$ is $\mathcal A$-measurable and bounded, $h_n$ is finitely $\mathcal A$-simple and it can be seen that $|f-g-h_n|\leq1/n$ and $|h_n|\leq|f-g|$ everywhere, which shows that $h_n=0$ a.e. and that $h_n\to f-g$ uniformly as $n\to+\infty$.

And the extension of $L$ is still a unital algebra homomorphism because if $\phi\to f$ and $\psi\to g$ and $\alpha\in\mathbf R$, then $\phi+\psi\to f+g$ and $\alpha\phi\to\alpha f$ and $\phi\psi\to fg$, so taking the limit in the relations $L(\phi+\psi)=L(\phi)+L(\psi)$ and $L(\alpha\phi)=\alpha L(\phi)$ and $L(\phi\psi)=L(\phi)L(\psi)$ tells you that the extension of $L$ is linear and multiplicative, and the relation $L(1)=1$ tells you that it is unital.

Thank you, now it is perfectly clear to me
